# How to create multiple markers with infoWindow showing google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm using google directions and make a route between two points and setting a marker and I need to set a window with some information in both of these markers, but According to [google](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/marker) I just can show a window one at the time! But in Uber App they did with both points.

[image]

This is what I did :

```
public void drawRoute(){
    PolylineOptions po;

    if(polyline == null){
        po = new PolylineOptions();

        for(int i = 0, tam = latLngs.size(); i < tam; i++){
            po.add(latLngs.get(i));
        }

        po.color(Color.BLACK).width(10);
        polyline = mMap.addPolyline(po);
        LatLng myCurrentLocation = new LatLng(lat, lon);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(myCurrentLocation, 11));
        Marker mMarker;
        mMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(finalLocaltion).title(finalLocationName));
        mMarker.showInfoWindow();
    }
    else{
        polyline.setPoints(latLngs);
    }
}
```

The window only appears when I click, and not by default!